# Adding domain name to ECS application with AWS ELB

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, amazon-ecs, aws-alb

I have an application which is running on an AWS ECS cluster which has 2 instances. I'm using EC2 instance type for ECS. I also have an application load balancer attached to this ECS cluster which uses dynamic port mapping. Right now, the application is working fine with the Load balancer's domain name.

I'm planning to add SSL feature for the load balancer and also a domain name for my application. For simplicity, I'm planning to use AWS ACM to create SSL certificates for HTTPS connectivity. But I'm not very aware of the domain name registration and all.

So I'm not sure on where to attach this domain if I go for a new domain registration. What IP do I use for domain registration? Or If I have a domain name, can I attach it to my application.

But still, I'm not sure where to point to. Any help regarding attaching domain to app with ecs and aws alb will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have to create an A record in your DNS server pointing to the ELB.
Amazon has Route53 for registering domains, if your domain is registered with Route53 it's easy as selecting the ELB from the list on the route53 console.
If you host your domain on a different registrar (e.g. GoDaddy) then make sure your ELB is publicly available and use its address for host address if your domain A record.

Comment: But how can I find out IP address corresponding to ALB. What I'm seeing is only a DNS name which resolves to multiple IPs.

Comment: right, so use the DNS name for the mapping, why would you want to use IPs, they might change

Comment: Done, that, but it is redirecting to a previous domain which was working on this ALB.

Comment: This answered all of my questions: https://serverfault.com/questions/560552/how-to-forward-godaddy-domain-to-ec2-load-balancer